# Creating a Markbook in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Markbook {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("What menu would you like to access? 0. Add Students 1. Change Mark 2. List Marks and Students");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


}
```

}

Is what I currently have, but I'm a bit rusty on my coding abilities, so I completely have no idea on how to start this off, would anyone be able to assist by giving tips or help?

Comment: What is this what are you trying to do can you be more specific? Just like you I have no idea how to start this off either.

Comment: Well, I've come back from a long period of time doing java, and I'm assigned to create a mark book of like 35 students and have to create certain menus to go into. I need to find out how to start the code to access those menus. I understand the code once you can select a menu and put information in there, I just don't know how to code the part where you actually select the menu itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the choices take the user input and process it

```
System.out.println("What menu would you like to access? 0. Add Students 1. Change Mark 2. List Marks and Students");
int choice = keyboard.nextInt();

if (choice == 0) {
    // run code for Add Students
} else if (choice == 1) {
    // code for change mark
} else if (choice == 2) {
    // list marks code
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    //  handle invalid input somehow if you want
}
```

Comment: No problem. Be sure to add more if statements if you add more choices.